# How to pass an array containing urls to an image source to imageadapter of the grid view?

Tags: android

how to pass an array containing urls as an image source to imageadapter of the grid view?
I have a working Image adapter. but the problem is the getView method of the adapter returns only one imageview. Can some one tell how to pass an array containing urls to the image adapter of the gridview ?  the getview method is here

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialise some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

    //  Bitmap bmp  = loadBitmap(url[i]);
        Bitmap bmp  = loadBitmap("http://www.fgj.com/aero/planes/boeing/boeingf15.jpg");
        System.out.println("in adapter :" + url[i]);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    //Bitmap bmp  = loadBitmap("http://www.fgj.com/aero/planes/boeing/boeingf15.jpg");
    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is *much* harder than it needs to be. The overview of what you need to do is:

1. Collect the urls you need to fetch.
2. Create an AsyncTask to fetch each one in turn *or* use a pool of AsyncTasks in a thread-pool fashion to service the urls. Somewhere you need to keep track of which url belongs to which position in your `AdapterView` so you can selectively invalidate rows as their images come in.
3. Cache the images you get back to the SD card or in memory.
4. Invalidate rows as their images come in, causing them to reload from the cache.

Personally I think the framework should supply a "WebImage" widget that would make this a bit easier. I guess there are just too many moving parts that it makes sense for each app to implement this on its own.

**Edit** - *unless* you use a library and let someone else do the dirty work. Apparently [DroidFu](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu/) has a solution for this problem: [ImageLoader](http://kaeppler.github.com/droid-fu/com/github/droidfu/imageloader/package-summary.html). I haven't used it, but it's probably less error prone than rolling one's own.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> list;//list of image paths
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/foldername/"+list.get(position));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(-1);
    return imageView;
}
```