# How to add drawables to a view programmatically from a URL but not in xml layout

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to create an Android View object dynamically and then add this view to a widget based on some user selection from a gallery. The problem is that it does not have setters for drawable resources. The only way to set the images is if I predefine an xml layout. I cannot then set the user selected images.

Even though I can create a view it will not have the right properties set. I tried implementing my own and exposing the drawables but then ran in to the issue "Class Not Found" and I've read its impossible to get around.

Is it possible to provide something in the AttributeSet on the constructor?

Really struggling, I don't even need a custom view if I could find a way to set the options.

```
 android:drawable1="@drawable/predefined_image"
 android:drawable2="@drawable/predefined_image"
```

And pass this via an AttributeSet since I know it just takes these and creates drawables from them.

---

Okay lets clarify the question a little,

I have an xml layout file

```
<AndroidSystemWidget
android:drawable1="@Drawable/drawable1"
android:drawable2="@Drawable/drawable2"
/>
```

Now I have 2 png files on the SD card
/sdcard/pictures/image1.png
/sdcard/pictures/image2.png

Now in the code there are no exposed setters for drawable1 or 2 there is only a single constructor

```
AndroidSystemWidget widget = new AndroidSystemWidget(Context, AttributeSet)
```

I want to create this AndroidSystemWidget in my widget configuration with the two png files above set to drawable1 and drawable2 and then set it via Views on the app widget provider.

Comment: Posting some examples of the code your trying to use might help people answer your question.

Comment: You can't reference file paths from xml as far as I know. Why not modify the widget instead?

Comment: I don't want to reference the paths from xml. The whole point is that I'm unable to use xml because I don't know what the images are before I enter the configuration screen and ask the user to select them from a gallery. I need to be able to set the 2 drawables 1 and 2 but outside of the XML but there are no setters for drawable1 and drawable2. That is what I'm struggling to do. I created my own version of the widget, but android does not let you use custom widgets.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is a little vague, so forgive me if I misunderstand, but you could simply use an `ImageView` and then set your image via `setImageFoo` calls:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

If you're using a custom view and drawing using canvas calls, then you can use the various `drawBitmap` routines as well.

If you're looking to load images over the network as your title indicates, then you may check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307678/hi-how-to-pass-an-array-containing-urls-to-an-image-source-to-imageadapter-of-th/5307812#5307812), which has a link to the DroidFu library as well.

Comment: I have a custom view but due to restrictions on the classes allowed to be added to a widget I must use an existing android app widget provider. The problem is that it can only have its properties set via xml, I need a way of creating the same xml setup but instead of using android:drawable="@drawable/resource1" I need to do this in code from a file path. There are no getters and setters exposed for the drawable's set in xml. Only attributeSet on the constructor. Oh and thanks for the link it'll come in handy for later ;)