# onClick change view attributes in custom grid view repeats itself?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Images becomes transparent in grid repeated manner rather than only clicked grid views.

```
    grid.setAdapter(gridadapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
              ImageView watched=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
              watched.setAlpha(50);
              Log.i(TAG,"Clicked");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an array containing urls to an image source to imageadapter of the grid view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307678/how-to-pass-an-array-containing-urls-to-an-image-source-to-imageadapter-of-the-g)

Comment: no that's completely different !! i am having problem with repeatation with attribute change of one sub  view of grid view